# Listing (counting) prototype functions

Tags: javascript

For example i have a simple object:

`var a = {};`

Is it possible to count or list all off this object prototype functions (like "toString", "constructor")?

Counting object 'a' functions:

```js
var a = {};
var prototypeFunctions = 0;
var props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a.constructor.prototype);

for(var i=0; i<props.length; i++){
    if(a.constructor.prototype[props[i]] instanceof Function){
        prototypeFunctions++;
    }
}

console.log("Number of object 'a' prototype functions: ", prototypeFunctions);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/wLb5dyrj/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Object.getOwnPropertyNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) on the prototype.

For example:

```js
var a = {};
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a.constructor.prototype));
```

Outputs:

```
[
  "__defineGetter__",
  "__defineSetter__",
  "hasOwnProperty",
  "__lookupGetter__",
  "__lookupSetter__",
  "constructor",
  "toString",
  "toLocaleString",
  "valueOf",
  "isPrototypeOf",
  "propertyIsEnumerable",
  "__proto__"
]
```

Note that this lists all direct properties of the prototype, and not those inherited from parents.

Comment: I'd use `getPrototypeOf` - there can be no `constructor`

Comment: @georg I'm not sure in what circumstance `constructor` can be null/etc, aside from manually setting it to null (and at that point, might as well assume the programmer also set `Object.getPrototypeOf` to null :).

Comment: for example, `a = Object.create(null); b = Object.create(a) `

Comment: This listing does not say anything about property type.